# How can I avoid having 10 nested loops in R?

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

I am trying to do the following in R : get every vector of the type

`c(a1, a2, ... , a10)`, where

`a1 < a2 < ... < a10`, and

`a1, ... , a10 in c(1:100)`.

This is possible using nested loops, with

```
for(a1 in 1:90) {

  for(a2 in (a1+1):91) {

for(a3 in (a2+1):92) {
```

etc...

But you'll understand why I'd rather avoid that solution. Furthermore, I'd like to be able to make both the number of a's and their range be parametrable, so as to get, for example, `(a1, a2, a3) in 1:10`

Does anyone have any idea as to how I might be able to do that? Keeping in mind that I do need to go through every possible combination of `(a1:a10)`, in order to be able to use the result in a later function.

Comment: `x = sort(sample(1:100, 10))` Change the `100` to the max value in `1:100`. Change the `10` to the number of `a's` you want.

Comment: Can you give an example of input and expected output, e.g. using 3 vectors each of length 3? It will make your question a lot clearer!

Answer (score 2):

Let's reduce the problem to `a1 < a2 < a3` taken from `1:5`:

```
combn(5, 3)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    2    2     3
#[2,]    2    2    2    3    3    4    3    3    4     4
#[3,]    3    4    5    4    5    5    4    5    5     5
```

How many combinations are that?

```
choose(5, 3)
#[1] 10
```

How many combinations are that for the problem as stated?

```
choose(100, 10)
#[1] 1.731031e+13
```

That's too many to calculate them all.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
sapply(0:10,"+",1:90)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11
# [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11    12
# [3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11    12    13
# [4,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12    13    14
```

Each column is your vector. Column 1 is 1-90, column 2 is 2-91,...,column 11 is 11-100.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a lot of combinations!

Here's a function to make it, but I can't get more than 4 numbers using 1:100 without running for a long time on my computer.

```
getcombinations<-function(size, maxn){
 as.data.frame(t(combn(seq(from=1,to=maxn),size)))
}
```

It works by using `combn` to take all the combinations of size from the `seq(1:maxn)`, then rearranging a little.

```
getcombinations(3,4)
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  2  3
2  1  2  4
3  1  3  4
4  2  3  4
```

Comment: That does look like what I'm looking for, thank you. I was wondering, though, if it does actually attempt to run on your computer. When I try with big values, R tells me that nrow is too large.